# how can I scale a tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

For example, I have a tensor shape is [128,128,3] and it's range is random,then I want to scale all nums in this tensor to [0,255],what function in tensorflow should I use to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more details on the max and min value of the range? You can try using `softmax()` if your range is from -inf to inf

Answer (score 5):

You can do the scaling by yourself.

```
// x is your tensor
current_min = tf.reduce_min(x)
current_max = tf.reduce_max(x)
target_min = 0
target_max = 255

// scale to [0; 1]
x = (x - current_min) / (current_max - current_min)

// scale to [target_min; target_max]
x = x * (target_max - target_min) + target_min
```

You just have to handle the edge case when all the values are equal.

Comment: Wouldn't a 255*`softmax()` be better here?

Comment: @martianwars softmax is not scaling in a linear way

Comment: Correct, but do you think it's a good idea if your range is -inf to inf?

Comment: @martianwars it really depends... for large input values exponential function would provide huge numerical issues I guess

Comment: I try it but get an error "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'min'",In fact I will have a X,it' shape is[batch_size,height,weight,channel],x'range not [-inf,+inf]

Comment: @Ginger its reduce_max/reduce_min I believe